# Measuring the distance between pixels on OpenCv with Python

Tags: python, opencv, raspberry-pi3, video-processing

I'm a newbie with Open CV and computer vision so I humbly ask a question. With a pi camera I record a video and in real time I can recognize blue from other colors (I see blue as white and other colors as black).

[image]

I want to measure the length of the base of the area (because I have a white rectangle and a black rectangle). This two rectangle together create the square frame.

[image]

Excerpt of code:

```
# Take each frame
_, frame = cap.read(0)

# Convert BGR to HSV
hsv = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)

# define range of blue color in HSV
lower_blue = np.array([80,30,30])
upper_blue = np.array([130,150,210])

# Threshold the HSV image to get only blue colors
mask = cv2.inRange(hsv, lower_blue, upper_blue)    
# applica filtri morfologici
mask = cv2.erode(mask, spotFilter)
mask = cv2.dilate(mask, maskMorph)
# ^Now the mask is a black and white image.
# ^Get height of the black region in this image

# Bitwise-AND mask and original image
res = cv2.bitwise_and(frame,frame, mask= mask)
cv2.imshow('frame',frame)
cv2.imshow('mask',mask)
cv2.imshow('res',res)
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Have you tried anything so far? StackOverflow isn't a free code-writing service, and expects you to try to solve your own problem first. Please update your question to show what you have already tried, showing the specific problem you are facing in a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). For further information, please see [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and take the [tour of the site](http://stackoverflow.com/tour).

Comment: I added the code

Comment: Can you add an example image to the answer?

Comment: I've added an image of the program. I should measure the distance (I've drawn a red line in the image)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming input frames will have "close to rectangle" shapes (where the following code works best), you have to use the `findContours` function to get the black region's boundary and `boundingRect`function to get it's dimensions.

```
mask = cv2.imread('mask.png') #The mask variable in your code
# plt.imshow(mask)
thresh_min,thresh_max = 127,255
ret,thresh = cv2.threshold(mask,thresh_min,thresh_max,0)
# findContours requires a monochrome image.
thresh_bw = cv2.cvtColor(thresh, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
# findContours will find contours on bright areas (i.e. white areas), hence we'll need to invert the image first
thresh_bw_inv = cv2.bitwise_not(thresh_bw)

_, contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(thresh_bw_inv,cv2.RETR_TREE,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
# ^Gets all white contours

# Find the index of the largest contour
areas = [cv2.contourArea(c) for c in contours]
max_index = np.argmax(areas)
cnt=contours[max_index]

x,y,w,h = cv2.boundingRect(cnt)
#Draw the rectangle on original image here.
cv2.rectangle(mask,(x,y),(x+w,y+h),(0,255,0),2)
plt.imshow(mask)
print("Distances: vertical: %d, horizontal: %d" % (h,w))
```

[image]